# Growth/Decay of an energy drink that contains caffeine problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I was helping a friend do a math problem, and I was pretty stumped as to why we couldn't get to the right answer

> Casey consumes an energy drink that contains caffeine. After consuming the energy drink, the amount of caffeine in Casey's body decreases exponentially. The 10-hour decay factor for the number of mg of caffeine in Casey's body is 0.2785.

Question `c` says:

> If there were 173 mg of caffeine in Casey's body 1.56 hours after consuming the energy drink, how many mg of caffeine is in casey's body after 2.56 hours after consuming the energy drink?

So, the first thing I did was calculate the 1.56-hour decay factor, which should be $${0.2785}^{(1.56/10)}$$ Which is $0.819$. So this is where I was unsure which formula to use, as there are two:

$$N(t) = N_0(e^{-rt})$$
and
$$f(t) = f_0 * (1-r)^t$$

So, I used both.

$$173 = N_0(e^{-0.819*1.56})$$
$$N_0 = 620.951$$
$$f(2.56)=620.951*(e^{-0.2785^{2.56/10}*2.56})$$
$$=98.0764$$

and

$$173 = N_0(1-0.2785^{(1.56/10)})^1.56$$
$$N_0 = 2493.65$$
$$f(2.56) = 2493.65(1-0.2785^{(2.56/10)})^{2.56}$$
$$=95.0563$$

Both of these answers are wrong. Am I doing something stupid here or what...?

Comment: There's only one hour for the 173 mg to decay...

Comment: Why do you say that? It says after 1.56 hours? @DJohnM

Comment: The decay period you're interested starts with 173 mg at the 1.56 hour point, and ends at the 2.56 hour point with ...?

Comment: Hmm... so what would the formula look like? Would it be $f(1) = 173*e^{(0.2785^{(1/10)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$N(t) = N_0\left(e^{-rt}\right) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

as a general [Exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) equation where $N_0$ is the amount at $t = 0$,  $N(t)$ is the amount remaining at time $t$ and $r$ is the exponential decay constant. You're specifically given that after $10$ hours, the decay factor is $0.2785$, i.e.,

$$\frac{N(10)}{N(0)} = \frac{N_0\left(e^{-10r}\right)}{N_0\left(e^{0}\right)} = e^{-10r} = 0.2785 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Taking the last $2$ parts of \eqref{eq2A} to the power of $0.1t$ gives

$$e^{-rt} = 0.2785^{0.1t} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This means that

$$N(t) = N_0\left(e^{-rt}\right) = N_0\left(0.2785^{0.1t}\right) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Also,

$$\frac{N(2.56)}{N(1.56)} = \frac{N_0\left(0.2785^{0.1(2.56)}\right)}{N_0\left(0.2785^{0.1(1.56)}\right)} = 0.2785^{0.1(2.56 - 1.56)} = 0.2785^{0.1} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Can you finish the rest?

Comment: Wouldn't it be N_0*e^(0.2785^(0.1*2.56)) for the first one, and similarly for the bottom (just puting e values)?

Comment: Why is equation 4 correct basically? How did you get from e^(-rt) = 0.2785^(0.1t)?

Comment: @JohnLexus Note $e^{xy} = \left(e^{x}\right)^{y}$. Thus, $e^{-rt} = \left(e^{-r}\right)^{t}$. From (3), you have $e^{-r} = 0.2785^{0.1}$. Thus, $e^{-rt} = \left(0.2785^{0.1}\right)^{t} = 0.2785^{0.1t}$.

Comment: @JohnLexus I realized a possibly more direct explanation is for me to take (2) to the power of $0.1t$ instead of $0.1$ so it more directly shows & can be used in (4). I hope that helps.

Comment: I see, should the answer be 152.24?

Comment: @JohnLexus That's the same answer which I got when I just did the calculations now.

Comment: I see... but I still don't understand what I was doing wrong. If e^(-rt) is the same as 0.2785^(0.1t), wasn't I doing that?

Comment: @JohnLexus You were calculating $e^{-rt} = 0.2785^{0.1t} = 0.819$ for $t = 1.56$. However, you then used $0.819$ as $r$ in your $173 = N_0(e^{-0.819*1.56})$ equation. Although $N_0$ is not needed in this case, to determine it, you would get that $173 = N(1.56) = N_0\left(e^{-r(1.56)}\right) = N_0(0.819)$ which gives $N_0 = \frac{173}{0.819} \approx 211.2$. Note one sanity check is that, after $10$ hours, the amount decays by about a factor of $4$ only, so after $1.56$ hours, the amount of decay will be a lot smaller factor.